# Checking if some date is after some months of the other day

Tags: java

I am given a date and a big number (which doesn't fit into long or int) which indicates the number of times some program should repeat (either weekly or monthly or daily). I want to know whether some day fits into the days of the program or not. For example, if I have a weekly repeat three times and the start is 2021_06_01, I need to have also the dates 2021_06_08, 2021_06_15, 2021_06_22. As long as the numbers fit into some array, I could do the following using Local-time-date class:

```java
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    eventDates.add(start.plusWeeks(i));
}
```

But since the numbers are very big it will give me not only memory limitations but also big execution time. Is there any alternative to do so? So that I can also handle very big numbers that also do not fit into Long?

Comment: Store the number in database or a file. Add dates in batches of say 4(a month). And weekly/monthly or after each execution add a new date to the list and subtract from the number.

Comment: Sorry, what. You have a number that is too large to fit into a 64 bit long ... telling you about number of days the program should be run? Errr, sorry. But do you understand how many days you are talking about here?

Comment: @GhostCat Yep the format I said only has 3 million and half days but that's not my invented problem it is a university assgnment :)

Comment: Could you post the assignment task? As long as you post your thoughts and attempts as well the question won't be regarded as a *homework dump".

Comment: `BigInteger` can hold big numbers.